# Как объединить два скрипта?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!
Как интегрировать один скрипт (выпадающее меню) в другой (иконка), или объединить их?
Скрипт выпадающего меню:

```
$(function() {
  $('.icon').click(function() {
    if($('#items').is(':visible')) {
      $('#items').removeClass('showitems'); 
    }
    else {
      $('#items').addClass('showitems'); 
    }   
 }); 
});
```

Скрипт иконки:

```
!function(a){a.fn.hmbrgr=function(b){function g(b){a(b).css({width:c.width,height:c.height}).html("<span /><span /><span />").find("span").css({height:c.barHeight,"border-radius":c.barRadius,"background-color":c.barColor,"transition-duration":c.speed+"ms"}),h(b)}function h(b){a(b).find("span").eq(0).css({top:d}),a(b).find("span").eq(1).css({top:e}),a(b).find("span").eq(2).css({top:f})}function i(b){a(b).on("click",function(c){c.preventDefault(),a(b).toggleClass("cross"),a(b).hasClass("cross")?j(b):k(b)})}function j(b){a(b).find("span").css({top:e}),setTimeout(function(){a(b).addClass(c.animation)},c.speed)}function k(b){a(b).removeClass(c.animation),setTimeout(function(){h(b)},c.speed)}var c=a.extend({width:60,height:50,speed:200,barHeight:8,barRadius:0,barColor:"#ffffff",animation:"expand"},b),d=0,e=c.height/2-c.barHeight/2,f=c.height-c.barHeight;return this.each(function(){g(this),i(this)})}}(jQuery);
$(function() {
$('.hmbrgr.four').hmbrgr({
    width     : 30,
    height    : 22,
    barHeight : 3,
    barRadius : 3,
    barColor  : '#2a2a2a'
});
});
```

Comment: А неотформатированного варианта второго скрипта нету?

Comment: В смысле объединить? И во втором коде что за обфуксицированная строчка?

Comment: второй код - это скрипт иконки http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Hamburger-Nav-Icons-using-CSS3-Hmbrgr/

Comment: Вот мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на класс .icon (а не только на саму иконку), раскрывалось меню, и при этом происходила анимация иконки. Вот и не могу это связать. А получается сейчас так, что при нажатии на класс .icon меню раскрывается, а иконка остается в том же горизонтальном положении (не меняется на крестик).